# How do I structure git to work with swappable 'modules' between projects?

Tags: git, github

I use React to display graphics for streaming. Each set of graphics (a graphics package) has its own git repo. When I am streaming for one project, I pick a graphics package to use for it. For the next project, I may use a different graphics package.

Each graphics package has a small amount of reused code - which may require updating as I refactor/add shared features

I also have other code that doesn't want to get swapped out for each project.

Currently I have a 'parent' git which is using submodules to add in the graphics packages and other shared code.

**Problems I'm facing:**

- I haven't found a good way to 'template' each graphics package in a way which I can later update all of them at once
- In the 'parent' repo, I am having to select which graphics package to use via a .env file or similar mechanism, but I have considered having a branch for each project. Is there a better way to have that separation for each project?
- Submodules is a bit of a pain but not a massive problem

Comment: Are there other modules used in more than one application?

Comment: There is a standalone 'control page' which can be run separately, however currently it's only used in conjunction with everything else in the 'parent' repo. Perhaps I'm trying to 'future-proof' (or at the very least, overthinking it) too early.

The only thing that actually changes between projects is the graphics package

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then I would keep the shared code in the supermodule (aka the parent repo).

If you can do that then you don't have to change it in every graphics submodule when it changes.

If for some reason you can't do that, then a really arcane approach would be to have each graphics submodule have a submodule of it's own, but all of the graphics submodules point to the same sub-sub-module.

That way you only have to update one place.
Don't try this unless you have to.
It could get very confusing. But if you set it up right it could also make the maintenance simpler.

Comment: Yes, it makes total sense to have that shared code in the supermodule. I think I was a bit deep in the weeds to see that. This is part of a large project and I tried to explain the situation with a simplified scenario.  


I was running into scoping and performance issues when I was working on all of the graphics packages at once which is why I tried to separate them, so maybe the sub-sub-module approach is what I'll try next.  


Any thoughts on using a separate branhc on the supermodule for graphics package 'selection'? Is there a smarter way to do that?

Comment: If you put the common code into the supermodule then I don't think you should need to take the sub-sub-module approach.

Comment: As for using branches to track the graphics package submodule, that seems reasonable to me. However there is one complication; If you change the common code, you will have to merge the change to all of the branches.